# Does the return statement work differently when the function is called outside the app server in Node.js/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

So I have this function I am calling outside of my app.js, it's another JavaScript file

```
const Lodash = require("lodash")
module.exports.postExist = function(posts, req) {
  let postValue = []
  posts.forEach(post => {
      if (Lodash.lowerCase(req.params.postName.toLowerCase()) === Lodash.lowerCase(post.title.toLowerCase())) {
        postValue = post;
        console.log(postValue + "inside");
        return true;
      }
    }
  );

  console.log("outside");
  return false
}
```

**Console log**

```
[object Object]inside
outside
```

The return value of this function is giving me `false` which I don't understand because the if statement is executed at some point from what I'm getting from the console log `[object Object]inside`, why isn't my function returning true and exiting the function. Why is it continuing the execution to my other return value?

Comment: The return value of a function called using `forEach()` is not used for anything.

Comment: Returning from the `forEach()` callback doesn't return from the caller.